Lando recipes are not available in Windows 11
I am using a Windows 11 machine with docker desktop and WSL.
I am trying to setup a new Drupal project (existing cloned one or recommended project clone using composer).
But whenever I am trying to initialize the project using lando init it gives me the following here.

What am I missed here?
I have php, composer, nodejs, npm installed in my system.
I am adding an update to Clives answer:
Its giving recipes options as none for new project also.


The same for me recipes = none.
Cannot install wordpress as plugin separately as well.

hi @user1113289 , i have a finding in my case in which i had to run the commands from inside the Linux WSL box. I was trying from outside. All the commands incuding lando should run from inside WSL i think
